# Delete column line in tabular

Tags: tables, columns

I have the following table, but I want to delete the two vertical lines in the GBM and MJD row:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|llr}
\toprule
%\multicolumn{4}{r}{GBM MJD} \\
%\cmidrule(r){1-2}
 &  & GBM& MJD\\
\midrule

 &1\%  & 1& 2\\
 Microsoft & 5\%  &1& 2 \\
 &10\%  & 1& 2\\  
   \midrule
 &1\%  & 1& 2\\
 Allianz & 5\%  &1& 2 \\
 &10\%  & 1& 2\\  

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

I want to delete the following lines:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 11):

You can do this using `\multicolumn` which has a width of `1` column; it may seem a little funny, but it's a standard way to fix this.

I've used

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
```

in the columns that you didn't want your `|`. You can read it as a 'multicolumn that spans 1 column, is centered, and has no content'. I also noted that you had an extra column in your `tabular` declaration which didn't harm things, but I've removed it.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test}

    \begin{tabular}{l|l|ll}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & GBM& MJD\\
        \midrule
                  & 1\%  & 1 & 2 \\
        Microsoft & 5\%  & 1 & 2 \\
                  & 10\% & 1 & 2 \\  
        \midrule
                  & 1\%  & 1 & 2 \\
        Allianz   & 5\%  & 1 & 2 \\
                  & 10\% & 1 & 2 \\  
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Some folks would recommend avoiding vertical lines altogether (including the author of the `booktabs` package), but that is personal preference.

Just for reference, if you use

```
\begin{tabular}{llll}
```

which removes all the vertical lines, then you get

[image: screenshot]

See also [Why not use vertical lines ('|') in a tabular?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40542/why-not-use-vertical-lines-in-a-tabular)

Another idea (thanks @doncherry,  @Qrrbrbirlbel) is to right align the columns and insert `<{\,\%}` between columns `2` and `3`; this requires the `array` package; note that this trick adds a `%` to each row in that column, so I've had to use the `multicolumn` trick again to remove it from the first row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test}

    \begin{tabular}{lr<{\,\%}cc}
        \toprule
                  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}   & GBM& MJD\\
        \midrule
                  & 1  & 1 & 2 \\
        Microsoft & 5  & 1 & 2 \\
                  & 10 & 1 & 2 \\  
        \midrule
                  & 1  & 1 & 2 \\
        Allianz   & 5  & 1 & 2 \\
                  & 10 & 1 & 2 \\  
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, there are lots of details to pay attention to when constructing a `tabular`! For future reading, you might also like to look at the [siunitx](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) which defines (among other useful commands) the `S` column type.

Comment: Those folks are right, of course. `;-)`

Comment: ok, what should I use instead of vertical lines? Thanks a lot for your help!  @cmhuges

Comment: @CoTabSu you're welcome :) see my update

Comment: @cmhughes you probably don't need the `\multicolumn` solution once you get rid of the `|` in the table definition. Doesn't change the output but makes the code clearer I think.

Comment: @doncherry @cmhughes `<{\,\%}` instead of `@{\,\%}` to get `\tabcolsep` back. That's the reason GBM looks so close.