# Table - remove row lines in column to furthest right

Tags: tables, rules, multirow

How do I remove row lines in the column to furthest to the right.
I have seen examples where they do it the left. I would like the "powers" from the [table here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Spanning_in_both_directions_simultaneously) to be on the right side instead of the left.

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%controls the space between the rows
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | l |}
            \hline
            \textbf{header one} & \textbf{header two} & \textbf{header three} & \textbf{header four}\\ \hline
             r1c1 & r1c2 & r1c3 &  \multirow{4}{*}{ no row lines in the first four rows}\\ \hline
            r2c1 & r2c2 & r2c3 & \\ \hline
            r3c1 & r3c2 & r3c3 &\\ \hline
            r4c1 & r4c2 & r4c3 &\\ \hline
            r5c1 & r5c2 & r5c3 &\\ \hline
            r6c1 & r6c2 & r6c3 &\\ \hline
            r7c1 & r7c2 & r7c3 &\\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \caption{my caption}
        \label{tab:test}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The text "no row lines in the first four rows" should have... well no row lines - it should be one "big box" :o) 
All help is greatly appricated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Maybe it should be mentioned that such "excel style" tables with a grid-like rules between all the cells are considered t6o be bad style in typography. Maybe you want to have a look into the quite comprehensive documentation of the `booktabs` package that elaborates a bit more on this topic and gives some nice alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
\cline{1-3}
```

in rows `2-4` instead of `\hline`

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%controls the space between the rows
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | l |}
            \hline
            \textbf{header one} & \textbf{header two} & \textbf{header three} & \textbf{header four}\\ \hline
            r1c1 & r1c2 & r1c3 &  \multirow{4}{*}{ no row lines in the first four rows}\\ \cline{1-3}
             r2c1 & r2c2 & r2c3 & \\ \cline{1-3}
             r3c1 & r3c2 & r3c3 &\\\cline{1-3}
            r4c1 & r4c2 & r4c3 &\\ \hline
            r5c1 & r5c2 & r5c3 &\\ \hline
            r6c1 & r6c2 & r6c3 &\\ \hline
            r7c1 & r7c2 & r7c3 &\\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \caption{my caption}
        \label{tab:test}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Further enhancements to your `table` can be made by employing the [`booktabs`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) package, and also noting the answers from

- [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables)
- [Why should a table caption be placed above the table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/why-should-a-table-caption-be-placed-above-the-table)
- [Why not use vertical lines ('|') in a tabular?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40542/why-not-use-vertical-lines-in-a-tabular)

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: true}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%controls the space between the rows
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{my caption}
    \label{tab:test}
    \begin{tabular}{  l  l  l  l }
        \toprule
        \textbf{header one} & \textbf{header two} & \textbf{header three} & \textbf{header four}                                  \\ \midrule
        r1c1                & r1c2                & r1c3                  & \multirow{4}{*}{ no row lines in the first four rows} \\ \cmidrule{1-3}
        r2c1                & r2c2                & r2c3                  &                                                       \\ \cmidrule{1-3}
        r3c1                & r3c2                & r3c3                  &                                                       \\\cmidrule{1-3}
        r4c1                & r4c2                & r4c3                  &                                                       \\ \midrule
        r5c1                & r5c2                & r5c3                  &                                                       \\ \midrule
        r6c1                & r6c2                & r6c3                  &                                                       \\ \midrule
        r7c1                & r7c2                & r7c3                  &                                                       \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: After your edit I wished there was a possibility to hit the upvote button a second time. Please add another thought upvote to your account ;-)

Comment: @BenediktBauer thanks a lot, you're very kind :)