# Creating a special table with different row lengths in latex

Tags: tables, tabularx

How can I have a table like the following picture in latex?
[image]

Comment: there is no problem in a `tabular` to end the current row with ` \\ ` at a time where less cells have been filled than in the preamble.

Comment: How can I put 20 in the middle of two corresponding rows?Since my second row is too long, I have to cut it and the rest write in the second row.

Comment: `multirow` will do it: see the answers.

Comment: Rather than splitting a row, I'd suggest to reduce the intercolumn space. Is the alignment between 45 and 34 in the “20 row” significant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution. I suggest [not using the vertical lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40542/13304), but rather the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package. For horizontal alignment of `20` you can exploit the [`multirow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) package, while for vertically alignment you can compute the width of the largest entry of the first columns via the [`calc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,calc,multirow}

\newlength\wdx% for vertical alignment
\setlength{\wdx}{\widthof{66}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}% increase distance between cells 
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\toprule
\textsf{x} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textsf{y}}\\
\cmidrule(l{\wdx}r{\wdx}){1-1}\cmidrule(l){2-6}
10 & 22 & 33 \\
\multirow{2}[2]{\wdx}{20} & 45 & 34 & 88 & 77 & 80 \\
 & 34 & 67\\
66 & 12 & 10 & 45 & 66\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could replace `\midrule` with `\cmidrule(l){2-6}` to make it more obvious, visually speaking, which columns pertain to "y".

Comment: @Mico: you're right, thanks! I'm editing the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you must use a vertical rule in your table, I would suggest you also insert "struts" to get better vertical spacing above and below the horizontal lines drawn by `\hline`. In general, though, I find it preferable to construct tables *without* vertical rules and to use the `booktabs` package to get well-spaced horizontal lines drawn by `\toprule`, `\midrule`, etc.

To vertically center the second entry in the first column, use a `\multirow` instruction.

You can also automate the job of making the first column always in bold.

Finally, if you want to use the `tabularx` package, say because you want to achieve a prespecified width of the table, and if you want the contents to be centered (which seems to be the case in the screenshot you posted), you will also need to define a special, "centered" version of the `X` column type that's provided by the `tabularx` package.

The first table below uses a `tabular` environment, and the second uses a `tabularx` environment with the total width set to `0.7\textwidth`. The second table is also set in sans-serif.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
% define "struts" as suggested by Claudio Beccari in
%    a piece in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993.
\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % = `top' strut
\newcommand\B{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % = `bottom' strut
\newcommand\TB{\T\B} % top-and-bottom strut 

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c|ccccc}
x & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\bfseries y\B}\\
\hline
10 & 22 & 33\TB\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{20} & 45 & 34 & 88 & 77 & 80\T\\
 & 34 & 67\B \\
\hline
66 & 12 & 10 & 45 & 66\T\\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\textsf{ % switch to sans-serif for the second table
\begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{>{\bfseries}C|CCCCC}
x & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\bfseries y\B}\\
\hline
10 & 22 & 33\TB\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{20} & 45 & 34 & 88 & 77 & 80\T\\
 & 34 & 67\B \\
\hline
66 & 12 & 10 & 45 & 66\T\\
\end{tabularx}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using, in addition of `array`, only the `makecell` package.  One advantage is that one can have much less tight rows with the `\makecell*` command (it adds `\jot` *symmetrically* at the top and the bottom of a cell, unlike `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{…}`. Another is the possibility to change hlines thickness (like `booktabs`, but keeping the possibility to use vertical lines).

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{array, makecell}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \centering\sffamily
    \addtolength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}% increase distance between cells
    \begin{tabular}{c!{\vline width1pt}*{5}{c}}
    \makecell*{x} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{y}\\
    \Xhline{1pt}
    \makecell*{10} & 22 & 33 \\
    \hline
    \makecell{20\\[-2.5ex]}& \makecell*[tc]{45\\34} & \makecell[tc]{34\\67} & 88 & 77 & 80 \\
    \hline
    \makecell*{66} & 12 & 10 & 45 & 66
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]