# Making a table with several lines in each box

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make a large table where each of the boxes has several lines of text underneath each other. I have tried `\newline` and `\linebreak` to get onto a new line, but neither work. The command `\\` does give a new line, but it ends the entire line in the whole table.

Can anyone suggest how I might get a new line, or perhaps a better package to use?

Comment: There are some suggestions in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485/how-to-break-a-line-in-a-table

Comment: Please always post a complete, Minimal (non-)Working Example of code which people can use to reproduce the issue. This makes your question a lot clearer, as well as making it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Not mentioned in the previous links, the `makecell` package defines `\makecell`, `thead`, `diaghead` and `\multirowcell` commands that accept the use of `\\`and can be further customised (choice of font, rotation, vertical spaces, &c.). One can change the hlines and clines thickness.

See [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165657/creating-a-special-table-with-different-row-lengths-in-latex) to have an example of its use.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parbox{}{}` as in:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \hline
        row 1, column 1, line 1 & \parbox{5cm}{row 1, column 2, line 1 \\ row 1, column 2, line 2 \\ row 1, column 2, line 3} \\ \hline
        \parbox{5cm}{row 2, column 1, line 1 \\ row 2, column 1, line 2} & row 2, column 2, line 1 \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions. The following demonstrates 2 approaches. The first relies on only standard commands. Although I've used `booktabs` for aesthetic reasons, this is not essential to the solution. The second uses `tabularx`.

[image: 2 ways to get <code>\newline</code> in tabulars]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}

One method involves using the standard \verb|p{<width>}| column specifier. This requires knowing how wide you want the columns but it allows you to use \verb|\newline| and does not require additional packages. Table \ref{tab:standard} does use commands from \verb|booktabs| to improve the tabular's appearance but you could replace with \verb|\hline| etc.\ if preferred.
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{.285\linewidth}}}
    \toprule
    row 1, column 1, line 1 & row 1, column 2, line 1\newline row 1, column 2, line 2\newline row 1, column 2, line 3\\\midrule
    row 2, column 1, line 1\newline row 2, column 1, line 2 & row 2, column 2, line 1 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tabular with standard commands}\label{tab:standard}
\end{table}
\bigskip

If you don't know how wide the columns should be and don't wish to figure it out, but you can specify the overall width of the tabular, \verb|tabularx| can be used. This supports the \verb|X| column specifier which figures out the width based on the overall tabular width. It also allows \verb|\newline|. Table \ref{tab:tabularx} again uses \verb|booktabs| but that is for merely aesthetic reasons.
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{.65\linewidth}{XX}
    \toprule
    row 1, column 1, line 1 & row 1, column 2, line 1\newline row 1, column 2, line 2\newline row 1, column 2, line 3\\\midrule
    row 2, column 1, line 1\newline row 2, column 1, line 2 & row 2, column 2, line 1 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Tabular with tabularx}\label{tab:tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```