# Automatic Table Widths

Tags: tables, width

This is probably a really simple question, but I don't know what keywords this question might have so I have trouble with searching it over the net. Anyway below is a code I wrote for a table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Sample} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Excitation Wavelengths}} \\ \hline
Chl-a           & \SI{415}{\nano\meter}     & \SI{570}{\nano\meter}    \\ \hline
Pheo-a          & \SI{415}{\nano\meter}     & \SI{620}{\nano\meter}    \\ \hline
Zn-Pheo-a       & \SI{420}{\nano\meter}     & \SI{604}{\nano\meter}     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Which generates a table that looks like this:
[image: Table Genrated From Above Code]
Now what modification should I use to bring the 2nd column cell border to the center?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please read [Why not use vertical lines ('|') in a tabular?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40542/why-not-use-vertical-lines-in-a-tabular)

Now, a possible solution with `X` columns form `tabularx` package. The problem is that a certain tabular width must be fixed as a first parameter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\small
\begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline
\textbf{Sample} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Excitation Wavelengths}} \\ \hline
Chl-a           & \SI{415}{\nano\meter}     & \SI{570}{\nano\meter}    \\ \hline
Pheo-a          & \SI{415}{\nano\meter}     & \SI{620}{\nano\meter}    \\ \hline
Zn-Pheo-a       & \SI{420}{\nano\meter}     & \SI{604}{\nano\meter}     \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you consider not to use vertical lines, an option could be:

[image]

which was done with

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\small
\begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{c>{\centering\arraybackslash}X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Excitation Wavelengths}} \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
\textbf{Sample} & $\lambda_1$ (\si{\nano\meter}) & $\lambda_2$ (\si{\nano\meter}) \\ \midrule
Chl-a           & 415     & 570 \\ 
Pheo-a          & 415     & 620 \\
Zn-Pheo-a       & 420     & 604 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I still have a bunch to learn. Anyway, changing the documentclass into \documentclass[a4paper,10pt, twocolumn]{scrartcl} screws up the table. Any reason for this? @Ignasi

Comment: @Vinsen With `twocolumn` use `\columnwidth` instead of `.5\linewidth`.

Comment: @Vinsen: Some more lecture ;)  http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16942/1952