# Macro: Replace all occurrences of a word

Tags: macros

I repeatedly use certain keywords such as `var` in my document which I highlight using `\src{var}`. This is cumbersome to type and gets annoying after a while. Repeatedly search-and-replacing `var` to `\src{var}` and then `\src{\src{var}}` to `\src{var}` also seems needlessly complicated. I want to tell LaTeX to replace all occurrences of `var` with `\src{var}`. I found `\def` that reduces the typing to `\var{}`, which is not much better. Something similar to the C preprocessor maybe: `#define var \src{var}`.
I found the "[Replacing all the dots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40828/replacing-all-dots-in-a-document)"-example but failed to modify it to "Replacing all the vars". Thanks for the help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: @PaulGessler Thanks for the edit, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a LuaTeX-based solution. It (i) defines a Lua function that changes all instances of "`var`" (note the spaces before *and* after "var") to "`\src{var}`"  and (ii) registers this function with the `process_input_buffer` callback. This callback operates on the entire input stream *before* TeX processes it. Separately, I define a TeX macro called `\src` so that TeX knows what to do when it encounters the instruction `\src{var}`.

With this setup, words such as "aardvark", "bivariate", and "covariance" are left alone. In the second input line below, the first and last instances of "var" are also left unchanged since they're not preceded *and* followed by a space. Finally, should there already be instances of `\src{var}` in your input file, they won't be operated on by the Lua function either -- they'll just get executed by TeX as one would expect.

Observe that nothing is written back to the `.tex` input file, i.e., your input file won't get littered with lots of `\src` statements.

By the way, I assume that the real string that's supposed to be operated on by `\src` in your file is a bit more unique than `var`. If so, you can probably dispense with the requirement that the string be both preceded and followed by a space.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xcolor}
\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase} 

\begin{luacode}
local function vartosrcvar ( line )
  return string.gsub(line, " var " , " \\src{var} ") 
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer",  vartosrcvar, "var_to_srcvar")
\end{luacode}

\newcommand\src[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}} % define "\src" to suit your needs

\begin{document}
aardvark bivariate covariance varnish

var uno var due var tre var
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is the way I will do it. I still need to skip the vars inside wavy brackets, define a list of keywords and a list of word seperators and let the script handle the rest. I am more comfortable with python and there is a Latex [python package](http://www.texample.net/weblog/2008/oct/24/embedding-python-latex/) that I will use. Thanks.

Comment: @nwp - Thanks! The pythonTeX package is indeed very nice. Just be aware that its output, unlike that of LuaTeX, won't be "real-time." I.e., you'll need (at least) one LaTeX run, one python run, and one more LaTeX run to fully propagate its output. That's not a strike against pythonTeX, of course.

Comment: @Mico So, when I try to compile your code with *Lualatex*, it seems we can significantly speed up the process (ommit loading a thousand or more fonts on the first run, by removing **\usepackage{fontspec}**)? + I would like to ask: How (most elegantly) to have multiple pre-defined strings of text being looked for?

Comment: @VincentVerheyen - The very first time one runs LuaLaTeX and loads the `fontspec` package, compilation indeed takes a fair amount of time, as the `luaotfload-tool` utility has to create a hash table of all properties of all fonts. The good news is that this is done only *once*. Moreover, FWIW, the font indexing program is a *lot* faster now than it used to be even just two or three years ago... On to your second question: Lua does pattern matching, not regexpes. Hence, the *general* answer to you question is, it can't be done. Can you give an example of the string searches you have in mind?

Comment: @Mico I found a way to have multiple pre-defined strings of text being looked for. The following does it for 2 (but it is easy to repeat the process for more): duplicate everything inside the `luacode`-environment, into a second `luacode`-environment below and then change `var` in `return string.gsub(line, " var " , " \\src{var} ") ` appropriately according to your purpose + change the name for each consecutive line of strings in `"var_to_srcvar"` arbitrarily.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen - OK, thanks for clarifying your objective. I was under the (evidently mistaken) impression that you wanted to set up a single command that does multiple string searches all at once.

Comment: @Mico What you suggest sounds elegant, and I was indeed looking for the most elegant way.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen - Yeah, and as I was trying to indicate earlier, this "most elegant" way isn't available in Lua -- unless you're willing and able load a whole regex library written specifically for Lua. :-( Consecutive `string.gsub` calls, while not the epitome of elegance, are not that bad, actually, unless one has hundreds of these calls...

Comment: @Mico Interestingly, sometimes one has to shift the order of the different lines of pre-defined strings (that is the positions of the different `luacode`-environments, such as the one in your code) inside the editor. If a larger string of text encompasses a smaller string of text, than the larger string of text needs to be loaded before the smaller one.

Comment: @Mico But I don't seem to be able to understand yet how to have other pre-defined lines of code, automatically colored, with different colour.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen - Please post a new query, in which you lay out all formatting requirements and objectives.

Comment: @Mico According to your advice, I have opened a new post at [Macro: Replace all occurrences of words (different automatic colouring for different sets of words)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305238/macro-replace-all-occurrences-of-words-different-automatic-colouring-for-diffe).

Answer (score 18):

TeX is a macro expansion system (like, but more powerful than) C's pre-processor but macros are introduced by `\` so use

```
\newcommand\var{\src{var}}
```

then  `zz zzz \var\ zzzz`

Or you could define (say) `|` to be an active character

```
\catcode`\|\active
\def|#1|{\src{#1}}
```

then  `zz zzz |var| zzzz`

It is, in theory, in very restricted circumstances, possible to get TeX to read ahead and look for `var` and use the syntax `zz zzz var zzzz` but I wouldn't seriously consider that, the contortions necessary to make it work will make your document massively fragile and incompatible with more or less any package.

Personally I'd use `\src{var}` Together with auto-completion in the editor so you don't have to type it all every time.