# From Capitals to Small Capitals

Tags: luatex, small-caps

If I have a font in which lookups exist c2sc as built-in, there is a command to make small caps capital letters without incurring complicated codes like this:
[Convert all-caps words to small caps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222804/convert-all-all-caps-words-to-small-caps)
I mean something like \textsc{...}, but with uppercase?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with textsc but with upper case? Do you want to convert to smallcaps? Or to normal caps? Something else? To make it a bit more concrete: can you provide a small document that illustrates what you want, with a screenshot of the current output and a description or mock-up screenshot of how you want the output to look?

Comment: Or do you just mean something like `\textsc{\MakeLowercase{YOURTEXT}}`?

Comment: Most caps/smcaps fonts have both styles.  Not tested: try `\MakeUppercase{Xxxx...}` to use the "real" uppercase.

Comment: Some OpenType fonts support this as a font feature, Capitals to Small Caps, which is available in `fontspec`.

Comment: I mean to write something like \textsc{TEXT} and obtain <TEXT> in small caps. My font has real smcp and two lookups: smcp (lowercase to small caps), which works with \textsc: and c2sc (capitals to smallcaps)

Comment: I use `\def\smcp#1{{\addfontfeature{Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps}#1}}`.

Comment: Fine, thanx! But is there a differenze in writing `\def\smcp#1{{\addfontfeature{Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps}#1}}` or `\newrobustcmd\smcp[1]{{\addfontfeature{Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps}#1}}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own declarations and commands for `c2sc` and for putting everything in small caps:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
%%% make uppercase letters small caps:
% declaration
\DeclareRobustCommand\csc{\addfontfeature{Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps}}
% command
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcsc}{\csc}

%%% make all letters small caps:
% declaration
\DeclareRobustCommand\asc{\addfontfeature{Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps,Letters=SmallCaps}}
% command
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textasc}{\asc}
\begin{document}
{\csc This declaration gives UPPERCASE SMALL CAPS.}

\textcsc{This command gives UPPERCASE SMALL CAPS.}

{\asc Now lower- and UPPERCASE letters are all small caps.}

This is \textasc{a TEST.} This is \textasc{only a TEST.}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

In most cases, there’s no advantage to doing this. But with EB Garamond and some commercial fonts, text in `\textsc{...}` copies as lowercase, while text set with `c2sc` copies as uppercase.

Comment: thank you. In any case \def is a Tex primitive, \newrobustcmd not and makes some contols before its execution. Here they are more or less the same