# Macro: Replace all occurrences of words which are identical to content of \label{...} into \nameref{...} (unless of course the \label itself)

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

This question is a follow-up of [Macro: Replace all occurrences of a word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165218/macro-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-word/165224?noredirect=1#comment740329_165224), but would like to ask for a possibility to do the same with words (e.g. **foo**) that are identical to the contents of certain or all `\label{`**foo**`}`s, and have those words automatically replaced into a `\nameref{`**foo**`}`s, unless of course for the one instance of `\label{`**foo**`}`.

*Explanation of the MWE below:*

The following contents of `\labels{`...`}` occur:

- **`\label{`The first section`}`**
- **`\label{`The foremost section`}`**

That means that every other instance of text which is identical to any such content (other than the instances of the `\labels{`...`}` itself of course) should be automatically changed into a `\nameref{`...`}` with those contents.

For example, any other occurence in the text of:

- **The first section**

should be turned into (I am talking hyper-markup here, `\nameref{` `}`should of course not be visible to the end-user):

- **`\nameref{`The first section`}`**

which could then automatically become a clickable link to the

- **`\label{`The first section`}`**

Analogue, this can be done for any number of labels (e.g. a **Second section**, a **Third section**, etc... could have analogue labels).

*Note: it should not only work for (labels near) Sections, but it would be nice to have it functioning for any labels.*

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{The first and foremost section, with 2 nice labels called ``The first section", and ``The foremost section" respectively (without parentheses).}\label{The first section}\label{The foremost section}

This is some text, now let's imagine that you want to refer \textbf{automatically} to the section above, by simply typing the following words: The first section.\\

Alternatively, the string ``The foremost section" (without parentheses) should also automatically be changed into a \textbf{nameref} which automatically links to the label accordingly.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Again, please provide an example making your intended usage clear and taking account of the restrictions you discussed with Mico in your other question.

Comment: Please provide a bit more detail -- preferably in the form (possibly nonworking) compilable code -- that illustrates what exactly you're looking to achieve.

Comment: @Mico + @ cfr -> The MWE (cf. above) just arrived from being *shipped out* in a compliable and compilable way.

Comment: This would be best done outside TeX. Find & replace in the editor is one option, but a simple script could handle this for all cases automatically.

Comment: You can't ping 2 people at once. The system will have told you that when you posted the comment.

Comment: This is not ideally done from within \*TeX. Any number of text processing languages-focused languages (e.g., `sed` or `awk`) would be far more suitable. And any decent editor (even if there's *really* only one decent editor) could easily solve this problem.

Comment: @jon What do you mean with "there's *really* only one decent editor": which one then? Is it easily shown how to solve the question with `sed` or `awk`, or should we not further go in to that, as that is off-topic for the **Tex** community here?

Comment: I was joking (... but it's [emacs](https://xkcd.com/378/)). It's a little off-topic as an answer though. But can't your editor do search-and-replace? Even word processors manage (almost) that much.

Comment: @jon But it is as **User nwp** said in the question linked in the current question: *Repeatedly search-and-replacing `foo` to `\...{foo}` and then `\src{\src{foo}}` to `\src{foo}` also seems needlessly complicated.* Further more, one could tap in to the centralized lay-out formatting of `\nameref{...}`s, just to mention one example of how centralizing these things can make things go quicker, and sometimes more accurate (imagine you add an extra instance of `foo` -> then correcting for it becomes extra work).

Comment: I cannot imagine why you'd ever end up with `\src{\src{foo}}` unless you used a careless search-and-replace method. I don't understand why you're not going straight from `foo` to `\src{foo}`.... Can't you simply search for ` foo` (i.e., with a leading space) and replace it with `\src{foo}`? TeX is not meant to be a swiss-army knife that you use for every type of problem (that's Perl!), so I can't endorse a non-TeX answer (even though they are possible).

Comment: @jon Not every instance in the text will always have a leading space (represented here as [space]), as such: `[space]foo`. There might very well be instances of `foo` (i.e. without leading spaces).

Comment: Hmm, well, it's impossible to give advice on how to write regular expressions when all the conditions aren't clearly laid out. You need to think about how `foo` will appear and what (I guess) it will be embedded in to write a proper `regexp` (for example, one step in the process could be to regularize how `foo` appears, if it's just going to be stuck in randomly as you are typing; then then next step would be to do a replacement -- not a difficult script in most cases).

Comment: @jon First, we could try a general answer, which would fit expected regular text cases?

Comment: I am sorry, but I'm not inclined to answer the general question when you already said it won't do what you need and that you anticipate asking for further modifications. Reliably good answers depend on good questions; and sometimes the questioner needs to do some of the hard work too.  (And of course there are many free online resources for using regexp and `sed`, which is what I'd use.)