# Automatically colourize all occurrences of certain strings (different colouring for different sets of words)

Tags: macros, color

This question is a follow-up of [Macro: Replace all occurrences of a word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165218/macro-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-word/165224?noredirect=1#comment740329_165224), but I would like the same for **different colours**, that is to have different pre-defined sets of text strings which will be coloured in a predefined way, where the colour depends on the set they are in.

**Requirement:**

- Each string should be able to include spaces and/or punctuation marks (e.g. a string could be **`foo's foo doesn't foo`)**.

*Edit: I was asked to provide a MWE, and while I was making one, suddenly I achieved [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305249/67761) which I failed in creating before. Trial-and-error-and-trial-and-success.*

Comment: Please provide a proper Minimal Example which demonstrates how you envisage this working and takes account of Mico's comments regarding the limitations of Lua's search-and-replace routine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Updated the answer after OP indicated that he/she uses the `book` document class and may have instances of search strings in the arguments of `\chapter` and `\section`.)

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. In addition to the Lua fuction, named `colorize`, that does the colorizing work, the code also sets up two TeX-side macros, `\colorizeOn` and `\colorizeOff`. As their names suggest, the macros serve to switch the operation of the Lua function on and off.

Some comments on the TeX-side code:

- If some of your search strings may occur in the arguments of `\chapter` and `\section` instructions, you'll need to provide all-uppercase aliases for the colors you'll be using. For instance, if the applicable colors are named `red`, `blue`, and `orange`, use `\colorlet` instructions to set up the aliased names `RED`, `BLUE`, and `ORANGE`.
- As far as I can tell, there is no good reason or valid excuse for letting search strings occur in the arguments of `\label` and `\ref`.

Some comments on the Lua-side code:

- `\` (a single backslash) is a special character in Lua. To generate a backslash in a `luacode` environment, one must write `\\`.
- The search and replacement patterns in the `gsub` function must be delimited by matching single (`'`) or double (`"`) quotes. If the search patterns contain quote characters *of the same type* as are used for the delimiters, the quotes inside the search pattern must be escaped by prefixing them with a `\`. (This isn't the case in the code below: there are two instances of `'` in the first search string, but they need not be escaped as `"` is being used to delimit the search pattern.)
- The characters `.` and `)` that occur in the first search string have a special, so-called "magical", meaning in Lua *if* they occur in a search string. To treat them as ordinary characters, they must be escaped with a `%` character.

  The following are Lua's "magical" characters: `(` `)` `.` `%` `+` `-` `*` `?` `[` `^` `$`. E.g., to search for a `%` symbol, write it as `%%` in the search string.

  No escaping of these characters is needed in the replacement string (the third argument of `gsub`), as they have no "magical" quality in the replacement string.
- The `%0` term in the third argument of `gsub` represents the entire string that was found by the pattern match.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} % choose various fonts, as needed

\usepackage{xcolor}  % for "\textcolor" and "\colorlet" macros
\colorlet{RED}{red}  % alias names for colors: use all-uppercase
\colorlet{BLUE}{blue}
\colorlet{ORANGE}{orange}

\usepackage{lipsum}  % filler text
\usepackage{luacode} % for "luacode" environment and "\luastring" macro

%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
function colorize ( buff )
   buff = string.gsub ( buff, "foo's foo doesn't foo%.%)", "\\textcolor{red}{%0}" )
   buff = string.gsub ( buff, "The quick brown fox",       "\\textcolor{blue}{%0}" )
   buff = string.gsub ( buff, "jumps over the lazy dog",   "\\textcolor{orange}{%0}" )
   return buff
end
\end{luacode}
%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\colorizeOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback 
   ( "process_input_buffer" , colorize , "colorize" )}}
\newcommand\colorizeOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback 
   ( "process_input_buffer" , "colorize" )}}
\AtBeginDocument{\colorizeOn} % turn Lua function on by default

\begin{document}

\chapter{The quick brown fox jumps}  

\section{Zorro jumps over the lazy dog}

(Every day, foo's foo doesn't foo.)

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\colorizeOff  % switch off the Lua function
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\colorizeOn   % switch Lua function back on
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.


\lipsum[1-12]  % filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have now asked a new question, since I would like to make your perfect answer compatible with another code; at the new question [Macro: compatibility of 1) Auto-colorization & 2) Auto-counter-and-title-to-label](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305863/macro-compatibility-of-1-auto-colorization-2-auto-counter-and-title-to-labe).

Answer (score 0):

The following is basicly just adapted from [User Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165224/67761) in the mentioned post "[Macro: Replace all occurrences of a word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165218/macro-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-word/165224?noredirect=1#comment740329_165224)":

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase} 

%%% RED SET %%%

\begin{luacode}
local function vartosrcvar ( line )
  return string.gsub(line, "colour it red" , " \\redder{colour it red} ") 
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer",  vartosrcvar, "red1")
local function vartosrcvar ( line )
  return string.gsub(line, "very red" , " \\redder{very red} ") 
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer",  vartosrcvar, "red2")
\end{luacode}

\newcommand\redder[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

%%% GREEN SET %%%

\begin{luacode}
local function vartosrcvar ( line )
  return string.gsub(line, "coloured it green" , "\\greener{coloured it green}") 
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer",  vartosrcvar, "green1")
\end{luacode}

\newcommand\greener[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}

\begin{document}

For example, here is a string which should be coloured red: colour it red.\\

Here is another string which should be ``coloured it red", it makes its very red.\\

Now, here should be a string, which should be ``coloured it green".

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need three separate `luacode` environments for the three functions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at your answer, which I just accepted as answering the question. Would you know how to answer an analogue macro-question [Macro: Replace all occurrences of words which are identical to content of \label{…} into \nameref{…}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305237/macro-replace-all-occurrences-of-words-which-are-identical-to-content-of-label)?