# It's possible, using LaTeX, to make something like a 'automatic reference'?

Tags: hyperref

I have, for example, a section of a book with the label 'Bases'.

I want to create a hyperlink every time I type 'Bases' in my text without putting a command like `~\ref{}`.

Comment: This would have to be done using LuaLaTeX, or via a processing of the entire TeX file using something like `sed`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Macro: Replace all occurrences of a word](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165218/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't simply use a new command?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\Bases}{Section~\ref{Bases}\xspace}

\begin{document}
    \section{Just for example}\label{Bases}
    This is the reference \Bases to the section.
    This is another reference \Bases.
\end{document}
```

The hyperlinks aren't shown in the image but there are in the `.pdf`:

[image]

If you use `fancyref` package it is better to put `sec:` before the reference name "Bases", see [LaTeX/Labels and Cross-referencing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a simple way of doing it. Just add a command for each word. The `\` behind the command in the text is just to make the following space character render as a space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\base}{\href{http://www.allyourbasearebelongtous.com}{base}}

\begin{document}
All your \base\ are belong to us!
\end{document}
```

Example output:

[image: All your base]

Comment: The OP talked about reference to a section of a book...

Comment: Of a external book? If not then just change my url code to internal ref?

Comment: No, the reference to the a section within the same document, see my answer for an example...

Comment: "If not then just change my url code to internal ref?" was my second question. And you showed this example in your answer.